# How to save and execute a python file?

Tags: python, shell, commands

I do not prefer `python-mode`. I would like a generic way so that I can understand emacs.

I wish the file be saved and `python file` command then be run as if in a shell.

Comment: You can run a shell under emacs: `M-x shell RET` and execute commands in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `M-!` (`M-x shell-command`) if you want to run a shell command,
e.g. `python file.py` and print the output in a new buffer (`*Shell
Command Output*`). That does not open a shell in a new buffer.

Use `M-x shell` to run a shell in a new buffer as pointed by @NickD.

Answer (score 1):

You could use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile` with an appropriate `compile-command` value.  e.g. as a file-local variable:

```python
# -*- compile-command: "python file.py"; -*-
```

Emacs will prompt you to save (or not) the file before running the command.